# regex with match in GREL/OpenRefine

Tags: regex, openrefine, grel

I'm using OpenRefine to parse a column with string values.
I want to find the cells that contain either: offer or discount.
The string value is usually a sentence

My code below is using the match function not working.
using `value.contains()` is limited to searching for one word only.

`value.match(/.*(offer)|(discount)/)`

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks a lot!. I'm new to stackoverflow, I wanted to thank you but the instructions said not to reply with Thanks...Anyways... I made some small changes: value.match(/.*((\boffer\b)|(\bdiscount\b)).*/).  I joined both groups with one parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions) is that the `.match` function *Attempts to match the string s in its entirety against the regex pattern p and returns an array of capture groups*.

To match either one of them but not both, you might use a positive and a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if that is supported.

To match either of the options, use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to make sure one of the words is there and the other one is not and vice versa:

```
(?:(?!.*\bdiscount\b).*\boffer\b.*|(?!.*\boffer).*\bdiscount\b.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wiq9xq/1)

That will match

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!.*\bdiscount\b).*\boffer\b.*` Assert that on the right is no discount and match any char and offer
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!.*\boffer).*\bdiscount\b.*` Or assert the opposite
- `)` Close non capturing group